# How to use HttpDelete and HttpPut for scala/etcd

Tags: scala, ubuntu, http-delete, etcd, http-put

Im trying to learn how to operate scala and the key-value etcd. I know how to post and get data from it. Atleast the entire key. In this case the entire "testDistrict" with everything it contains. But I cant figure out how to delete and put. So do you know?
Im trying to use httpDelete and httpPut. But cant get it to work. See the pictures:[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the httpDelete. It is to add "?recursive=true" at the end of "/keys/testDistrict"